# Blinker/Marker light issue

Tags: electrical, headlight

Just recently got this issue while replacing the headlight housings on my 03’ Chevy S10.
After I replaced them i noticed the right side blinker/marker light bulb had gone out, so i went to O’Reillys got a new one and replaced it. Whenever i went to test out the blinker i noticed that 1. The blinker indicator on the dash was solid and 2. If i actually used the left blinker it would blink rapidly, not at its usual pace. I later noticed the marker light is not on but if i use my blinker it blinks(they share the same bulb). I have tried; replacing it with a new bulb, switching the bulbs. But nothing changes.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like a bulb, instead it's probably the signal flasher relay which has failed. The relay is a switch that turns the light on and off on a timer. When these relays fail you get rapid blinking or the light constantly staying on, which is just what you describe. They either look like a little box or a little cylinder with prongs sticking out. They're pretty cheap and you can install it yourself, you just pull the bad one out and push the replacement in.

I don't know the S10, and there's conflicting reports of the relay location, but all seem to agree it's under the dash on the driver's side. Some say it's in the driver's side fuse box to the left of the steering column, other reports say it's between the gas and brake pedals.

Comment: Saw your comment and instantly went to replace the relay, now its blinking normally but the marker light is still not on and the blinker indicator is still solid on the dash